# Why does System.Memory have a dependency on System.Numerics.Vectors in .Net 4.6.1 but not in .Net 4.6?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

These are dependencies of Nuget package `System.Memory`. We use older .Net framework versions and I noticed that if I use 4.6.1, there is an additional dependency on `System.Numerics.Vectors` (a framework DLL I think) which isn't needed in 4.5->4.6.

It seems the opposite to normal, that a *newer* version of .Net would require more dependencies.

Why is this, and will I see any difference e.g. in performance?

[image: Additional dependencies]

Answer (score 4):

> It seems the opposite to normal, that a newer version of .Net would require more dependencies.

The `System.Memory` package contains libraries for the following target frameworks.

- .NET Framework 4.6.1
- .NET Standard 2.1
- .NET Standard 2.0
- .NET Standard 1.1

### .NET Framework 4.5

When consuming the package in a .NET Framework 4.5 project, the `System.Memory.dll` from the **.NET Standard 1.1** target is used, because that is the highest version that it can consume, see this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support). However, this version does not use `Vector<T>` or other vector types. Consequently, it does not depend on `System.Numerics.Vectors`.

### .NET Framework 4.6

The same as for .NET Framework 4.5 applies, since **.NET Standard 1.3** is the highest version that a .NET Framework 4.6 project can consume. As there is only a .NET Standard 1.1 version provided, it will fall back to that.

### .NET Framework 4.6.1

When consuming the package in a .NET Framework 4.6.1 project, the corresponding version of `System.Memory.dll` is used. This version uses the [`Vector<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?view=netcore-3.1) type which is only available in:

- .NET Core >= 1.0
- .NET Standard >= 2.1 Preview
- The `System.Numerics.Vectors` NuGet package

The .NET Framework 4.6.1 target has a dependency to the `System.Numerics.Vectors` package, because it would not be available otherwise.

> [...] will I see any difference e.g. in performance?

There might be a performance benefit, since `Vector<T>` is a [SIMD-accelerated type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/simd). It is used in a helper class for spans, where [`Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector.ishardwareaccelerated?view=netcore-3.1) is checked, so I guess there is a performance-related reason behind using `Vector<T>`.

### Bonus Round

Why does that package even have a separate .NET Framework 4.6.1 target, if it could could use .NET Standard? That is best explained in the linked reference itself.

> [...] While NuGet considers .NET Framework 4.6.1 as supporting .NET Standard 1.5 through 2.0, there are several issues with consuming .NET Standard libraries that were built for those versions from .NET Framework 4.6.1 projects. [...]